# How can I remove elements in an iframe using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have added link elements  to an iframe´s (ivuFrm_page0ivu1) content and would like to remove these upon selecting a button. The code I am using is here:

```
function removeAddedElements(){

console.log("called removeAddedElements()");
$("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1").contents().find(".linkUp").each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).remove
    console.log("removed one linkUp");
});
}
```

It iterates over the four elements I have, but does not remove them. They stay visible. How can I remove these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove` is not a valid function in `jquery`. Try   `$(this).remove()`

```
function removeAddedElements(){

    console.log("called removeAddedElements()");
    $("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1").contents().find(".linkUp").each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).remove()
        console.log("removed one linkUp");
    });
    }
```

[Documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: thanks a million! I will accept as soon as the 10 minutes are over!

Comment: I am glad it helped you.